# Why AVR-GCC compilers append a "clr r1" line after multiplication?

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I am trying to check how AVR-GCC compiler compiles for multiplication?

Input c code:

```
unsigned char square(unsigned char num) {
    return num * num;
}
```

Output assembly code:

```
square(unsigned char):
        mul r24,r24
        mov r24,r0
        clr r1
        ret
```

My question is why it is adding the statement `clr r1`? Seemingly, one could have removed this statement and still got as desired, assuming the parameter is stored in r24 and the return value is available at r24.

Direct Godbolt link:
[https://godbolt.org/z/PsPS_N](https://godbolt.org/z/8Fbqk-)

### UPDATE:

I also see related more general discussion [here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/isr-prologueepilogue-optimization-avr-gcc).

Comment: It's not related to the `mul` specifically, but part of the function calling convention as specified by the ABI. There will be a bunch of registers that must be used in a certain way during function call and return. In case of low-end microcontrollers, apart from automatic stacking of certain items, there's rarely a standardized cross-compiler ABI, so each compiler typically does as it pleases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When GCC's AVR backend was implemented and the [avr-gcc ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Register_Layout) was devised, it turned out that code generation can be improved in some situations when there is a register that is known to contain `0`.  The author chose `R1` back then, i.e. when avr-gcc is printing assembly instructions, one may assume that `R1=0` like in this example:

```
unsigned add (unsigned x, unsigned char y)
{
    if (x != 64)
        return x + y;
    else
        return x;
}
```

This compiles with `-c -Os -save-temps` to the code below.  It uses `R1` aka. `__zero_reg__` so it can print a shorter instruction sequence:

```
__zero_reg__ = 1
add:
    cpi r24,64
    cpc r25,__zero_reg__
    breq .L2
    add r24,r22
    adc r25,__zero_reg__
.L2:
    ret
```

`R1` was chosen because in an AVR, the higher registers are more powerful and therefore register allocation starts – with a grain of salt – at the higher registers, hence the low registers would be used last.  Thus a register with a small register number was used.

This special register is not managed by the register allocator, it is "fixed" and managed by hand.  This was all simple with the early AVRs which didn't support `MUL` instructions. With the introduction of `MUL` and cousins however, things got more complicated because `MUL` is using register pair `R1:R0` as implicit output register and hence overrides the `0` held in `__zero_reg__`.

Thus you can implement two approaches:

1. Emit `CLR __zero_reg__` *prior* to each use so `R1` contains `0`.
2. Clear that reg 'after' a sequence that clobbered it.

The avr backend implements approach 2.

Because in the current avr backend (at least up to v10) this register is managed by hand, there is no information whether clearing that register is actually needed or might be omitted:

```
unsigned char mul (unsigned char x)
{
    return x * x * x;
}
```

produces with `-c -Os -mmcu=atmega8 -save-temps`:

```
mul:
    mul r24,r24
    mov r25,r0
    clr r1
    mul r25,r24
    mov r24,r0
    clr r1
    ret
```

i.e. `R1` is cleared *twice* even though right after the 1st 'CLR' the 'MUL' instruction is overriding it again. In principle, the avr backend could track which instructions clobber `R1` and which instruction (sequence)s require `R1=0`, however this is currently (v10) not implemented.

The introduction of `MUL` lead to yet another complication: `R1` is no more *always* zero, i.e. when an interrupt triggers right after a `MUL` then the register is in general *not* zero.  Thus an interrupt service routine (ISR) must save+restore it when it might use `R1`:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

char volatile v;

ISR (__vector_1)
{
    v = 0;
}
```

Compiling, assembling and then `avr-objdump -d` on the object file reads:

```
00000000 <__vector_1>:
   0:   1f 92           push    r1
   2:   1f b6           in      r1, 0x3f
   4:   1f 92           push    r1
   6:   11 24           eor     r1, r1
   8:   10 92 00 00     sts     0x0000, r1
   c:   1f 90           pop     r1
   e:   1f be           out     0x3f, r1
  10:   1f 90           pop     r1
  12:   18 95           reti
```

The payload of the ISR is just `sts ..., r1` which stores `0` to `v`.  This requires `R1=0`, hence the need for `clr r1`, hence save-restore `R1` by means of push+pop.  The `clr` clobbers the program status (SREG at I/O address 0x3f), thus SREG must also be saved-restored around that sequence, and in order to accomplish that the compiler is using `r1` as a scratch register as special function registers cannot be used with `push`/`pop`.

Apart from that, there are situations where there is *no* reset of zero-reg after a `MUL`:

```
int square (int a)
{
    return a * a;
}
```

compiles to:

```
    mul  r24,r24
    movw r18,r0
    mul  r24,r25
    add  r19,r0
    add  r19,r0
    clr  r1
    movw r24,r18
    ret
```

The reason there is no `CLR` after the 1st `MUL` is because the multiplication sequence is internally represented and then emit as [one chunk (insn)](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/avr/avr.md;h=4278fdf820974672d525cc1cacfc3fa38d760400;hb=c891d8dc23e1a46ad9f3e757d09e57b500d40044#l3212), hence there is knowledge that there is no need for an intermediate `CLR`.  In the example from above with `x * x * x` however, the internal representation is two insns, one for either multiplication.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a matter of [the AVR ABI used by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc).  In particular:

> **R1**
>
> always contains zero. During an insn the content might be destroyed, e.g. by a MUL instruction that uses R0/R1 as implicit
>   output register. If an insn destroys R1, the insn must restore R1 to
>   zero afterwards. [...]

And that's exactly what you see in the assembly.  R1 is clobbered by the `MUL`, so it must afterward be cleared to zero.